# ScrollView с обеими прокрутками

Tags: android, map

Хочу сделать карту для игры, в которой будут по нужным X и Y выставляться `View`. Карта естественно будет больше экрана. У меня два вопроса

- получится ли выставлять по координатам `View`, если карта будет больше экрана?
- возможна ли одновременная прокрутка? Тоесть свайп по диагонали скроллит карту в обоих направлениях, а не только в одном

Comment: Такое предчувствие, что мне нужен `WebView`, но как нам динамично выставлять элементы, это же не контейнер

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android

Comment: @Leonid, все, второй вопрос решен :) Осталось первый, сомнения развеять

Comment: Должно получится, ведь ScrollView для этого и создан, чтобы уместить и показать всё, что не вмещается на экране. Другой вопрос, а оно Вам надо? если цель - создание игры, удобнее использовать libGdx

Comment: @Leonid, нет нет нет, только не это. Нужен только элемент интерфейса. Карта с кликабельными элементами. Хорошо, попробую, спасибо :) Оформите ответ